Using a comma before "nevertheless" and "however"
In my book "Good punctuation" by Graham King pg 51 he writes.."it is customary to use commas to enclose modifying adverbs and adverbial phrases such as 'however','nevertheless'
e.g. 'you are, nevertheless, guilty of the first charge'. While he does mention that enclosing commas are increasingly dropped when the meaning is clear without them (book is 20 years old) — this seems to be clearly at odds with www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/conjunctive_adverbs.htm and https://www.grammar.com/however/#:~:text=If%20you%20use%20however%20to%20join%20two%20independent,comma%20before%20the%20however%20is%20a%20gross%20mistake. which says "If you use however to join two independent clauses, you must end the first clause with a semicolon and put a comma after however. Using a comma before the however is a gross mistake"
Unless I'm mistaken, this means that either Graham King (or the websites) is wrong — which would surprise me — or in the 20 years since the book was released the comma before "however" has been avoided like the plague.
Can anyone please clarify what is correct here. Thanks

Your book and that website are talking about different things, adverbs and adverbial phrases on the one hand, and independent clauses on the other.

I thought "you are" is an independant clause as it has a subject "you' and a verb "are" —the website is saying you shouldn't put a comma before 'however/nevertheless' when joining two independent clauses.

In your example, "You are, however, guilty of the first charge", however is between "You are" and its complement, "guilty of the first charge".  The complement is not a clause.

@TimR So "however" is not joining two clauses together but in fact splitting a single clause "you are guilty of the first charge" — correct? If so that would mean "however" is not functioning as a conjunction adverb; what is it function as?

It could be called a "connective adjunct".  A connective adjunct can set up a contrast with a preceding sentence. For example, "You have been found innocent of tax-evasion. On the count of obstruction of justice, however, you have been found guilty."

@TimR I finally came across https://www.sjsu.edu/writingcenter/docs/handouts/Conjunctive%20Adverbs.pdf which explains pretty much everything I was looking for — except when you end clause or sentence with an CA e.g. "...still loved it, though" is this an interrupter word too?

There's not contradiction. The two sources are talking about different things.
If I have a short paragraph:

Cats are cute. However, my cat is ugly.

The word "However" is at the start of a sentence.  I could decide that the two sentences are closely related, and then I could use a semicolon:

Cats are cute; however, my cat is ugly.

That is what grammar monster instructs you to do. The word "however" does not join the clauses.  It does indicate how the second clause is related to the first one.
It further says that using a comma to join the two clauses is a "gross mistake".

? Cats are cute, however my cat is ugly.

Now, you could also move the word "however" later in the second sentence. If so you should enclose it in commas

Cats are cute. My cat, however, is ugly.

That is what Graham instructs you to do. It is correct to use commas. You don't need a full-stop or a semi-colon, because the word "however" isn't at the start of the sentence. The word "however" does not join the clauses.  It does indicate how the second clause is related to the first one.
but he notes that the commas are sometimes dropped

Cats are cute. My cat however, is ugly.

Words like "however" help to show the relationship between ideas in sentences, such as cause and effect, contrast or sequence. Unlike coordinating conjunctions (and, but, so...), Such adverbs can be  flexible in their placement within a sentence. -- they don't have to be at the start of the clause to indicate the relationship that the clause has to others.
-

I understood all that except for...Now, you could also move the word "however" later in the second sentence. If so you should enclose it in commas
Cats are cute. My cat, however, is ugly. — if "however" is a conjunction adverb (unless you are saying its not, or functioning as something else here) and a conjunction adverb connects two independant clauses: this is what the website is saying to avoid, having a comma before "however" when connecting two independant clauses?

I've edited to clarify.  The grammar monster is just saying, "End a sentence with a full-stop (or semicolon)"  If you write "Cats are cute. My cat, however, is ugly."  then the sentence ends with a full-stop.  So that is correct.

Where I am getting stuck is if a conjunction adverb like "however" can be used in the middle or at the end of a clause — then how is it performing its function of joining two independent clauses or sentences?

Its not "joining two indpendent clauses together"  It doesn't "join" anything.  It indicates a relationship between the two clauses, but the two clauses remain separate. They aren't "joined".

James K I'm a bit lost https://www.scribbr.com/commas/comma-before-or-after-however/#:~:text=When%20it%E2%80%99s%20not%20being%20used%20as%20a%20conjunctive,separated%20from%20the%20following%20clause%20with%20a%20comma. are saying 'connect' or 'join' independent clauses; am I misinterpreting what they are meaning? www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/conjunctions/conjunctive-adverbs also https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parts-of-speech/conjunctive-adverbs/?msockid=0cdcc7f240676cea07f6d3b741796da6

Please read again.  Your link does not say "join" at all.  And is says that it is a mistake to use a comma to connect two clauses, unless you use a coordinating conjunction like "but".  The word "however" does not join anything.  It does tell you how two clauses are related.

Is there any actual example that you are not sure about?  Can you give a single example of a sentence that you can't tell if it is correct or not.

"Conjunctive adverbs are parts of speech that are used to CONNECT one clause to another" from www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/conjunctions/conjunctive-adverbs AND "transition words used to CONNECT independent clauses or sentences" FROM https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parts-of-speech/conjunctive-adverbs/?msockid=0cdcc7f240676cea07f6d3b741796da6

Conjunctive adverbs are words or phrases that connect two independent clauses or sentences. They help to show the relationship between ideas in sentences, such as cause and effect, contrast or sequence. Unlike coordinating conjunctions (and, but, so...), conjunctive adverbs can be more flexible in their placement within a sentence. FROM https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/conjunctive-adverbs.php   "..connect two independent clauses.." "conjunctive adverbs can be more flexible in their placement within a sentence" — how can a CA connect two clauses when at mid or end of clause

@RoostyBoy thanks,  adopted/adapted

thanks; to summarise all this time I've been thinking that a Conjunctive adverb has to PHYSICALLY connect two clauses but what you're saying is it just has to (for lack of a better word) SPIRITUALLY connect two clauses

You are correct - when used as a conjunctive adverb, 'however' can only (i) start a sentence, or (ii) follow a semicolon. The fact you can begin a sentence with the word proves that it can introduce an independent clause, so any two independent clauses joined with a comma instead of a semicolon would be a comma splice (a common error).
Your textbook that says otherwise is not so much 'wrong' as misleading. What it actually says is that it is "customary" to "enclose" adverbial phrases with commas, which is true as many will be parenthetical. Although 'however' would not appear in the middle of a sentence between two commas, a word or phrase at the beginning or end of a sentence, offset by a single comma, can often be considered parenthetical even though there is only one comma. Parenthetical commas don't have to be 'opened and closed' the way parentheses (brackets) do. The big mistake is the use of the word "enclosed" which means from all sides, suggesting a comma before and after. If it had said "offset" or something similar then I'd have no issue with it and it would reconcile with your conflicting text.
